# store the number of times a document was seen in a given time period

Tags: solr

I am parsing documents on the web and storing them in solr database. Every day I see thousand of documents and some of them are repeating.

I'd like to give user an option to see which document was most seen on a given date, or in a given timespan. Queries of interest correspond to:

```
-show me which documents were seen the most on 16/10/2022,
-show me which documents were seen the most between 16/10/2022 and 23/10/2022
```

When writing solr queries, you specify field name to search on. What field type should I use and in what format should I store the number of times the document was seen on a given date?

Comment: name can be anything like viewCount and you can make it as numeric....you can use this while filtering the document or sorting the documents based on view count

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and stopping by.  just having `viewCount` is not enough. I also need to connect viewCount with a given date. Not only that, solr query needs to be able to sum viewCount for all the dates in the query (it could be whole year) and sort it. storing viewCount for each day in a separate field would results in hundreds of fields and I am not sure if that is the way to go.

Comment: oh ok...The expectation is too high from the document oriented database...Here you are expecting one to many relationship...One document will have datewise views...Either you need to repeat the documents...(which is not a good suggestion) or you need to maintain a relationship between the data(which is not advisable with NoSql kind of DB)

Comment: Thanks. Are you aware of database technology that would made such queries possible and fast?

Comment: You can use a separate collection to store day/view numbers, which you can the aggregate up using the facet JSON API, then fetch the documents from your main collection. That will allow you to have a separate collection that is used for statistics, which you can configure in any way you want. Other options is to use a time series database (Influx, TimescaleDB, etc.), but whether it's relevant for performance you'll have to evaluate yourself. A Solr solution will probably be performant enough, dependening on the number of document ids you want to keep track of.

Comment: You can also use the streaming expressions API to perform analytics like this on a collection, where you retrieve the most viewed set of documents from within a time period by rolling up statistics over an id and then sorting the resulting set further.

Comment: @MatsLindh 1/2: Thank you for commenting. I like the first approach, but it may not satisfy all search features. My understanding is a bit shaky so let's go through steps in more detail.  Step 1 is to create a collection with fields `id`(same as document id), `date` and store each document view as a separate document in the new collection. Step 2 would be to run `http://localhost:8983/solr/select?facet=on&facet.field=id&facet.field=date` to give you views. This particular facet search is not the correct one, because it will return 2 arrays, one for id and one for date.

Comment: @MatsLindh 2/2:  I do not know what the step 3 looks like :) Note that users may only want to find the most viewed document in a time period belonging to a certain category or country or containing specific keyword. Would the approach above be able to handle such queries?

Comment: There's a reason why I mentioned the [JSON facet API](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/json-facet-api.html) and not the old API - it's far easier to define buckets and aggregate functions on those buckets in the JSON facet API. The strategy would be to have a terms facet on id, then another facet on those buckets that have `sum(hits)`  (see "Nested facets" in the JSON facet article). The documents would have `id`, `date`, `hits` as their fields, allowing you to sum up the number of times you've seen each document that day. You can then sort the parent facets by that value

Comment: As shown in the reference guide for sorting facets by nested functions https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/json-facet-api.html#sorting-facets-by-nested-functions - if you need to filter by other fields, I'd suggest adding those fields to the stats collection, or query the original collection to get the ids, then querying the stats collection with those ids. There's also the option of exploring a cross collection join: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/join-query-parser.html#cross-collection-join for filtering.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll test it out. On a side note, do you recommend and resource for learning solr besides the docs? I started with a book from 2014 but have struggled with it due to incompatibilities between solr version v4 and v9.

Answer (score 0):

How I would try it:

- Create a separate collection - very simple collection with fields:

  - view time
  - doc id
  - title or body (whatever you're querying)
    ... do this for EVERY view.
- you can query it by the gap you want:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/query -d 'q=title:abc&rows=0&json.facet={
 per_month: { range : {
  field : last_modified,
  start:'2022-01-01T00:00:00Z',
  end:'2022-12-31T23:59:59Z',
  gap:'+1MONTH',
 }}
}}
```

This would return all views by MONTH (can change it to DAY, YEAR, etc).

But your doc is probably too big for this solution.  If you want to normalize this:

[a JOIN query](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/join-query-parser.html).  Since solr 8.6, you can now do cross-collection joins on multiple shards.  [this is a good article about how to do those queries](https://kmwllc.com/index.php/2020/07/15/the-cross-collection-join-query/).  [this is a decent video of how to set this up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyMkwmAoplI)  It's not that hard to do.

The JOIN query would be *much* faster.

If you don't want to do the JOIN query:

- If the views change often, do not store them in the document store.  There's no notion of partial updates in solr.  If you're updating views every day, you'll need to update every document that's been viewed.  That's going to cause a lot of unnecessary disk thrashing.

Other thoughts:

- can you use a database?  This is a far better use of views.  Solr isn't good as a master record for views.
- Another suggestion is to make the views go to an analytics engine - a far better solution since you can get rich analytics about the actual users. An analytics engine does a lot that rendering views does not - especially filtering out false positives (like bots!).  It's not fun to maintain an accurate view count if you have a high-trafficed site.
- In the past I've used an analytics engine to collect the data and used the analytics engine to export that data into solr.  This way you can have the view logic be done by the software component that knows views best (the analytics engine like Google analytics or Salesforce marketing engine) and run an hourly process to update the views in solr using one of the above tactics.